# Replacing a column in a matrix by its Log

Tags: matrix, replacement, column

I have a nx3 matrix (called Plottable) filled with non-negative reals and I am trying to change the third column to its logarithm, but the /. operator doesn't change anything in the matrix. If I try the same thing on something simple like identity matrix the outcome is as desired. Any thoughts why it doesn't work on bigger matrices? (I've also tried ReplaceAll, but with same outcome..)

[image: The code in question]

Answer (score 5):

In the newest version you can do:

```
mat[[All,3]] //= Log[#+1]&
```

Older versions:

```
mat[[All,3]] = Log[mat[[All,3]]+1]
```

Comment: Well, I have no idea why ur command works and what I wrote didn't, but it solved my problem so I am grateful

Comment: I would *not* advocate for using Replace or ReplaceAll in these cases. There is no need to match, since you just want to perform a function to some data. So it can be done directly using Set, ApplyTo, or SubsetMap. All quite equivalent…

Answer (score 3):

Let's create an example matrix.

```
(amat = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.89219 & 1.95383 & 1.58845 \\
 1.46229 & 1.57794 & 1.20504 \\
 1.99951 & 1.96593 & 1.29309 \\
 1.91897 & 1.65612 & 1.74091 \\
 1.21452 & 1.05846 & 1.31039 \\
 1.62685 & 1.30253 & 1.37783 \\
 1.44643 & 1.39972 & 1.65927 \\
 1.08318 & 1.45507 & 1.64689 \\
 1.52817 & 1.73258 & 1.24356 \\
 1.27712 & 1.57854 & 1.18252 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using pattern matching:

```
(bmat = amat /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, b, Log[c]}) // MatrixForm
```

Here I am assuming that you want the zeros to translate as $-\infty$. If not, use the  desired function for `c`.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1.89219 & 1.95383 & 0.462757 \\
 1.46229 & 1.57794 & 0.18651 \\
 1.99951 & 1.96593 & 0.257033 \\
 1.91897 & 1.65612 & 0.554405 \\
 1.21452 & 1.05846 & 0.270322 \\
 1.62685 & 1.30253 & 0.320507 \\
 1.44643 & 1.39972 & 0.50638 \\
 1.08318 & 1.45507 & 0.498891 \\
 1.52817 & 1.73258 & 0.217981 \\
 1.27712 & 1.57854 & 0.167648 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

OR using `SubsetMap`: (once again use the desired function)

```
(cmat = SubsetMap[Log, amat, {All, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

Comment: I would *not* use ReplaceAll in such cases, what if there are 3 entries rather than 10?  Then it would match at the highest level first, rather than each row. 
```ConstantArray[5, {3, 3}] /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, b, Log[c]}```. Better use Replace or SubsetMap Indeed…

Comment: @SHuisman Good point. How about: `(amat /. {x___, {a_, b_, c_}, y___} -> {x, {a, b, Log[c]}, 
     y}) // MatrixForm`?

Comment: The better way of fixing this is not using ReplaceAll (/.) but rather Replace with a level specification, or even better use directly Set, ReplacePart, SubsetMap, ApplyTo etc…. And the code you provided, only matches a single time. i.e. it replaced the 3rd only of the first row…